# What is the probability of drawing kings

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

A hand $H$ of 5 cards is chosen randomly from a standard deck of 52. Let $E_1$ be the event that $H$ has at least one King and let $E_2$ be the event that $H$ has at least 2 Kings.
What is the conditional probability $\mathbb P(E_2 | E_1)$?

Solution: The number or hands $H$ with $\ge1$ king is $\binom{52}{5} - \binom{48}{5}$ and all these hands are equally likely. Among these, the number with exactly one King is $4\binom{48}{4}$. Therefore, $\mathbb P(H\textrm{ has exactly one King}|H\textrm{ has }\ge1\textrm{ King})=\frac{4\binom{48}{4}}{\binom{52}{5} - \binom{48}{5}}$.

What we want is the complement, namely $\mathbb P(H\textrm{ has}\geq2\textrm{ Kings}|H\textrm{ has }\ge1\textrm{ King})=\mathbb P(E_1|E_2)=1-\frac{4\binom{48}4}{\binom{52}5-\binom{48}5}.$

---

Can someone explain to me how they went from $\mathbb P(H\textrm{ has exactly one King}|H\textrm{ has }\ge1\textrm{ King})$ to $\mathbb P(H\textrm{ has}\geq2\textrm{ Kings}|H\textrm{ has }\ge1\textrm{ King})$ just by taking the complement, maybe I just don't understand how the complement works (I'm only clear on taking the complement of a the probability that a hand has no king to determine the probability that it has one king).

Answer (score 2):

The complement works here because the probability is conditional to there being at least one king. Complement of '$H$ containing exactly one king' is 'either $H$ has no kings or $H$ has at least $2$ kings. But $Pr(H$ has no kings | $H$ has at least one king) is zero. So complement of $Pr(H$ has exactly one king | $H$ has at least one king) gives the required answer.